# How can i make foundation global variables available to all my scss files in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I was wondering how i could make the color variables (e.g. $light-gray) available accross all my scss (i am using foundation 6).

I thought using `*= require foundation_and_overrides` at the top of my application.scss would make all variables available accross all scss files but i get the follwing error `Undefined variable: "$light-gray".`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the best practice. But I do it in such a way that I have another scss file called `shared_variables.scss`

```
// shared_variables.scss
$light-gray: #ccc;
```

Then inside `foundation_and_overrides.scss`, I import it (if you're going to use a variable in this file):

```
// foundation_and_overrides.scss

// ...
@import 'foundation-functions';
@import 'shared_variables'; // Add this line
// ...
```

Then import that as well for any other `.scss` file that depends on the global variables;

```
// posts.scss
@import 'shared_variables'; // Add this line

.posts-container {
  background: $light-gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we can't use @import to make a variable globally. This is the reason:

> Sass/Sass will take the file that you want to import and combine it
>   with the file you're importing into so you can serve a single CSS file
>   to the web browser.

Check [this](http://sass-lang.com/guide) for more detail

Let's say you have a couple of Scss files, `_reset.scss` and `base.scss`. We want to import `_reset.scss` into `base.scss`.

**_reset.scss**

```
html,
body,
ul,
ol {
   margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**base.scss**

```
@import 'reset';

body {
  font: 100% Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

The `base.scss` will be generated to `base.css` like this:

**base.css**

```
html, body, ul, ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 100% Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

So `import` works like replacing `reset` content to the position importing `reset` in `base`!